# Show common values in a column once in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K0', 'K0', 'K1'],'cat': ['C0', 'C0', 'C1', 'C1'],'B': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3']})
df
Out[15]: 
  key cat   B
0  K0  C0  A0
1  K0  C0  A1
2  K0  C1  A2
3  K1  C1  A3
```

Is it possible to convert it to:

```
   key cat B
0  K0  C0  A0
1          A1
2  K0  C1  A2
3  K1  C1  A3
```

I want to avoid showing same value of `key` & `cat` again and again and `key` reappears once `cat` changes.
It's for an excel purpose so I need it to be compatible with:

```py
style.apply(f)
to_excel()
```

Comment: They are not duplicates in the sens of rows but just the same value with the columns `key` and `cat`. I want to show them just once

Comment: `df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['key', 'cat']), ['key', 'cat']] = ''` ..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) over a subset of the columns to look for duplicate values:

```
cols = ['key', 'cat']
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=cols), cols] = '' 

  key cat   B
0  K0  C0  A0
1          A1
2  K0  C1  A2
3  K1  C1  A3
```